# React: Getting is not defined no-undef error

Tags: reactjs

Good day, please am trying to fix my Vscode react.js, all the code i inserted inside the App.js is cutting please how can i fix this, and when i try lunch it through browser i get from both the vscode and the browser [codeerror.jpp[browsererror.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIzAm.jpg)

have try to update my vscode to the latest version and restart my browser countless time, still receiving same problem

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import CarList from './component/CarList';

function App() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        < CarList />
      </div> 
    );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Because you left a space to write the name of the component, please delete it, I will give you the code: ```<div><CarList/></div>```

Answer (score 0):

You should write this way

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import CarList from './component/CarList';

function App() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <CarList />
      </div> 
    );
}
export default App;
```